# Game freezes on Android Lollipop (version 5.0)

Tags: android, multithreading, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop, glsurfaceview

I am developing a game using GLSurfaceview and OpenGL ES 1.1. In my game, the game region (created using GLSurfaceview) is zoomed in (zoom-in animation) when the game is launched.

**Issue:**
I have found that sometimes the game freezes in zoomed out state after launching the game on Android Lollipop (version 5.0). The zoom-in animation doesn’t start and game remains in the zoomed out state until I kill the game.
This game is running properly on all Android versions starting from 1.6 (Donut) to 4.4.4 (Kitkat).

In my code, I have two threads running in the game.

1. Game Logic thread: Thread for updating the variable used for animation
2. Game Render thread: GLSurfaceview thread used for rendering the game region

In my code, the above threads start when the game is launched. Game logic thread continuously updates the value of animation variable. This variable is used by the Game Render thread to show the zoom-in animation.

Code to start Game Logic thread:

```
mHandler.removeCallbacks(GameLogic);

mHandler.postAtFrontOfQueue(GameLogic);
```

Here, mHandler is a Handler class object.

From my code, I understand that this issue can occur when the Game Logic thread is stopped. But I am not able to figure out how the Game logic thread stops on Android Lollipop, as I am not pausing or resuming the Game Logic thread via code.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :**
Animation code

```
Game Logic() {
                if (anim_counter == 144) {
                    stop_animation();
                } 

                anim_counter += 2; // update animation counter 

              }
```

Comment: Is there a stacktrace for the game logic thread? Perhaps you can start by searching and examining every while loop, every piece of code that has to wait for something and seeing if there are any circular references or two objects waiting on each other to complete. These problems can occur in so many ways that more information is likely required.

Comment: Attach a debugger and figure out what each thread is doing when the game is frozen.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, I am not able to replicate the bug again so I don’t think attaching the debugger or trying a stacktrace will be helpful. As soon as the game logic thread is started, it begins incrementing the variable value used for animation so I don’t think that there are any dependencies between objects that would block the incrementing of the variable. This incrementing of the variable does not require any prerequisite to satisfy. I’m providing the code in the edit section that increment my variable that I suspect may have gotten stuck.

Comment: Please let me know if there is any other information that I could provide that would help you assess the bug.
Also, has anyone had a situation where they were not able to replicate a bug and were not able to find a problem in the code? Did they go ahead release the product? I’m asking because this is my last remaining bug.

Comment: I have a similar problem, except in my case the network thread is freezing. Works on kitkat and down, but not on lollipop. Im rewriting the network thread on my own instead of using boost, to see if I can understand the problem better.